# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in Eclipse even though the mysql-connector jar is referenced

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I know this has been asked before, but in my case, adding the library (Rightclickling project>Buildpath>Configure buildpath>Add External JARs> Select JAR) hasn't worked and I still keep receiving the error.

Here's my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
            getConnection();
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            String driver = "com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "admin";

            Class.forName(driver);

            //Creating a variable for the connection called "con"
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            System.out.println("Connected");
            return con;

        } catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

        return null;
    }
}
```

And "mysql-connector-java-52.40-bin.jar" appears under "Referenced Libraries".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add your full error message to your question

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I'm an idiot. It has to be "jdbc" instead of "jbdc". Carry on.